# Euclidean distance vs cosine distance in sparse vectors - How come Euclidean performs better?

Tags: python, performance, math, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a dataset of very sparse vectors `df` (over 95% zeros) and I am measuring the distance between another sparse vector `sample`.

Now since I'm dealing with very sparse vectors, I assumed cosine distance would be calculated much faster than euclidean, but that doesn't seem the case.

Is this normal behavior? Or am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's not even true that cosine distance is more efficient in sparse vectors?

(`all_distances` include many types of distances, but the only ones we are talking about here are `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` and `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`)

My code

```
for d_name, d_func in all_distances.items():

    tot_time = []
    for i in range(100):
        start_time = time()
        df['distance'] = df.apply(d_func, axis=1, args=(sample,))
        df.sort_values(by='distance', ascending=True, inplace=True)
        df.drop('distance', axis=1, inplace=True)
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        tot_time.append(time() - start_time)
    
     print("Mean time for {}: {}s".format(d_name, round(mean(tot_time), 4)))
```

Result:

> Mean time for cosine: 0.8034s
>
> Mean time for euclidean: 0.708s

Comment: Explain why you think one should be faster (just because of sparsity).  It doesn't look like you are using `scipy` `sparse` matrices.

Comment: Looking at the formula https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine I can see that no calculation are needed for elements that zero at either of the two vectors, so I believe the iteration in cosine should be much faster, since 95+ precent of the time either of the two elements in the same index would be zero.

Comment: and no I'm not using `scipy.sparse` I've actually never touched it, if it would boost the cosine performance, I would love to hear I to use it in this use case

Comment: Testing for zeros also takes time; functions don't usual add that step unless they expect sparse inputs.  Even then it is better if they are told ahead of time which calculations to skip.  Pandas has its own sparse code.

Comment: So how would I go about dealing with different distance function in sparse vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Cosine similarity needs the norm of both input vectors, as well as the dot product between them:

```
cos(theta) = dot(a,b) / (norm(a) * norm(b))
```

So, even though the dot product only accumulates when both `a[i]` and `b[i]` are nonzero, you still need to accumulate the norm for both `a` and `b`, which itself is about as much work as accumulating the Euclidean distance.

Most of the work will be in iterating through the sparse vectors anyway -- note that there is not actually much difference in performance between them.  However, a plausible explanation of the difference is that the cosine computation needs to do slightly more arithmetic.

Comment: Certainly there is a way to avoid calculating the norms, if the dot is zero.. No ?

Comment: True, but that won't save you much time -- as most of the work is iterating through the sparse vectors.  Then, if the dot *isn't* zero, you will need to re-iterate through the sparse vectors again to compute the norms, which will almost double the time required.  If you were writing `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`, would you take that bet?

Comment: Obviously not, but looking at their docs I couldn't find anything in the sparse related modules. This is getting a bit off topic, but any known solutions for math with sparse vectors? I mean, I saw scipy sparse library, distances is pretty basic and it's not there